# Hide details in the Category Blog menu and display them in the single article

Tags: menu

Is it possible to display details information (author, create date, ...) in the articles but hide it in the blog page (with multiple articles)?

I noticed that if I create a Home menu with the Category Blog type and hide all the details in the blog then these detailes are hidden in the articles too when I open them. If I move the Home menu say to the second position the details are shown/hidden correctly (hidden in the blog, shown in the single articles).

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, you don't really give all the necessary information, though.

The article links in the blog view are just that: links to the articles. If your blog view menu item is the first menu item that shows the correct category, that is used with its hide details settings. If before that you have another menu item that can show the article its settings are used instead.

Normally this is done with a separate menu that isn't assigned to any module and doesn't do anything except provide overrides to how articles are shown. In addition to content component settings these hidden menus can also be assigned modules, template styles, and plug-ins, so you can fully configure how the articles are shown.

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by editing template's PHP code. I'm using Joomla 4 with default Cassiopeia template. I will use 'category` as an example. i.e., I want 'category' to be shown in a single article, but not shown in blog category. You can apply this method to other details (like 'Published date', 'Hits', etc) as well.

1. Login administration page, click `System` at the left side-bar.
2. Click `Site templates`.
3. Click `Cassiopeia Details and Files`.
4. Click `Create overrides`.
5. Click `joomla` at the `Layouts` column. This will expand that directory. Then click `content`. You can see a successful hint.
6. Click `Editor`, navigate to the directory you just created, namely `templates/cassiopeia/html/layouts/joomla/content`.
7. Click `info_block.php` under this directory to edit it.
8. In the first PHP code block, add one line of code:  `$isCategoryView = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view') == 'category';`. The variable `$isCategoryView` represents whether current view is 'category'.
9. Find this line with a if-sentence `<?php if ($displayData['params']->get('show_category')) : ?>`. Add an additional condition to this 'if', makes it `<?php if ($displayData['params']->get('show_category') && !$isCategoryView) : ?>`.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612051/how-to-detect-if-the-page-is-a-joomla-article-or-category-blog-view) at the Stack Overflow.